# 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll An unhandled exception of type

Tags: c#, ios, wpf, user-interface, diagram

I am creating a diagram designer and i add a button on it to save the GUI as an image. i create a class DiagramDesignerExporter and i have this code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace DiagramDesigner
{
    class DiagramDesignerExporter
    {
        public static void ExportToPng(UIElement target, string ImagePath)
        {
            // Prepare target-layout
            Size size = target.RenderSize;
            target.Measure(size);
            target.Arrange(new Rect(size));
        // Render diagram to bitmap
        RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap =
            new RenderTargetBitmap(
                (int)size.Width,
                (int)size.Height,
                96, 96,
                PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        renderBitmap.Render(target);

        // Convert bitmap to png
        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(ImagePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            encoder.Save(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I call it like this in the button:

```
DiagramDesignerExporter.ExportToPng(this, <YourFullFilePath>);
```

I am hoping for your help. Any suggestions will do. Thanks :)

Comment: Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Thesis(Back Up)\UML Communication Diagram Maker\DiagramDesigner\bin\Debug\Users\Sony\Pictures'.                                                                              That was on the error too.

Comment: Does that directory exist?

Comment: Actually I see from your second post that it wasn't.   

"D:\Thesis(Back Up)\UML Communication Diagram Maker\DiagramDesigner\bin\Debug\Users\Sony\Pictures" was missing.

"C:\Users\Sony\Pictures" is access denied.  Different errors.